# Visual Studio MySQL difference for 64 bit systems?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

I am working with a 32 bit Windows, Visual Studio and MySQL. All works fine when I deploy the application for x86 and x64.

But it seems that the MySQL commands and connections don't work on 64 bit systems. Do I have to make changes for 64 bit systems ?

My code is like this :

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Sub recording()

    Dim s(2) As String
    Dim bk As New MySqlConnection("SERVER=11.111.11.11;Database=abc;uid=def;pwd=ghi")
    Dim km As New MySqlCommand


    s(1) = Date.Today
    s(2) = TimeOfDay

    Dim ip As New WebClient

        bk.Open()
        km.Connection = bk
        km.CommandText = "insert into xxx(Date,Time)values ('" _
            & s(1) & "','" _
            & s(2) & "')"
        km.ExecuteNonQuery()
        bk.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: _don't work on 64 bit systems_ well what problem do you experience with this code? I see at least two big errors here but they are not connected to 32 vs 64 bit systems. Do you have any error message to tell us?

Comment: No, me personally, when running it on my own 64 bit computer it works. But on other computers it doesn't as far as I check the database. The code is shortened here, normally ,it is longer but I get no errors for it. Is there something fundamental to change for 64 bit ?

Comment: Well what is the error on the systems where it **doesnt** work.  Maybe it just cant find the DB

Comment: Or the rules that convert a date and a time to a string are not the same expected by your database or you are using reserved keywords. It seems strange that you don't get any error message unless you are actively suppressing them like using an empty try catch.

Comment: The application is used worldwide, so I don't know. I only know that I don't get database entry from 64 bit machines. The path is similar to the 32 bit application.

Comment: @MehmetKeskin that's because there are two versions of the connector's: `(mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-win32.msi)` and `(mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.6-winx64.msi)`... You have to choose which one...

Comment: @zaggler That may be the answer, thank you. Can I install the 64 bit connector for VS on my 32 bit system ?

Comment: @Steve :) I am using try catch, I just simplified the code for display, but the reason for that is something else not the date-time format

Comment: So how do I switch from one connector to the other, 32 to 64 ?

Comment: Which version of Connector/Net are you using?  I just checked the download page and I don't see two editions for the latest version. There's only one that says "x86, 32-bit". I don't know whether that means that it will only work with 32-bit apps or not. If so then you would need to set the Target Platform of your project to x86 so that it will run in a 32-bit process on 64-bit machines too.

Comment: Connector Net 6.9.8. I am using Visual Studio and the only difference I make from 32 to 64 bit is to change the "Target Platform" of the "Setup/Deployment project" - thats near to what you described but no 64 bit records enter the database.